# Spacing different between two different versions of XeTeX

Tags: spacing, titlesec

I am struggling with a project where the output is different depending on the PC I build the LaTeX file. I have reduced my original document to this snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[fontsize=6.5pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}

\allsectionsfont{\sffamily\underline}

% This behave different depending on the XeTeX versions
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{-3pt}{-1pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{-4pt}{-2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\section*{Foo}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\section*{Bar}

Curabitus dictum gravida mauris.

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

On XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/Debian):

[image]

On XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6.0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/Debian):

[image]

We can observe that the spacing are different across XeTeX versions. What's wrong there?

Comment: The LaTeX document in your hyperlink requires the file `revision.tex`, which isn't available on the GitHub site. Is available online somewhere else?

Comment: the different OS is almost certainly not the issue, it will be different macros or different fonts. add `\listfiles` to the document and compare the file lists. (Please don't use external links for code, make try to make a self contained example and add it to the question)

Comment: @Mico it is created during the build process

Comment: Which build process?

Comment: @Mico There is a Makefile on the project sources. This Makefile creates the revision.tex file. But as the version number is visible on both PDF, it should not be part of the problem

Comment: I really don't think it's reasonable to expect the readers of your query to jump through pointless hoops, such as running build processes via some makefile. Please make your query self-contained.

Comment: I have edited my question with a short example.

Comment: `sectsty` and `titlesec` don't go along; also `parskip` is involved in the issue.

Comment: why are you using inputenc and T1-fontenc with xetex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Curiously because otherwise I have a warning coming from whatever package.

Comment: well neither package is suitable for xelatex, so better remove them and solve the warning whatever it is correctly.